# Why cant i reassigned a variable defined in a function inside another function also inside it?

Tags: python

This is my first question here so i'm sorry if it's badly asked.

I have this function:

```
def game():
 potion_strength = 0
 def upgrade_potion():
   potion_strength = 2
 
 upgrade_potion()
 print(potion_sttrength)

game()
```

I would expect this to print 2, but it prints 0 and i can't understand why. I tried using the `global` keyword in `upgrade_potion()` and it still doesn't work. Can someone help me please? If `potion_strength` is inside the `game()` function why isn't it being reassigned?

Comment: in the inner function declare `nonlocal potion_strength` (not `global`, as it is not global), as otherwise (like you have it now), `potion_strength` will be considered a separate local variable, that just happens to have the same name.